# I'm using three20 in an iphone iOS 4 project. I cant compile the project to the device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, three20, armv7

I try to compile but it fails because it find a duplicated definition of class in one of the dependencies and in the main dependency. I googled a lot and i even found the cause of this, due to a bug in xcode and the optimization for amr6 and arm7 code. But i could't found how to solve this. Has anybody use the three20 library with iOS4 ?

Comment: I had this bug with other dependent projects. The only way I made it work was to start a new project in xcode and move everything to it.

Comment: See if the answer to my question is of any assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206999/static-library-dependency-compiles-in-simulator-on-xcode-3-2-3-fails-on-device

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all dependency projects are set to use the base sdk, then it should compile ok.