# Xcode vs. static library vs. armv6

Tags: iphone, xcode, static-libraries

I have a home-rolled static library to which I link my iPhone app. Works great in Debug mode for Simulator, armv7 (iPhone 4), and even in my unit test app in OS X (GHUnit). However, when I try to run debug my app on my iPhone 3G with iOS 3.0, no dice. The app dies in runtime when it tries to access my library classes.

Both the app & library have

```
Architectures:       Standard (armv6 armv7)  
Valid Architectures: armv6 armv7 i386
```

I'm linking with "-ObjC -all_load", and I've seen some [indications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300867/3153354#3153354) that -all_load can cause problems with fat binaries. Yet the armv7 version is working fine. Anybody know what's going on here? Is there a magic build incantation I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite similar to [Static library dependency compiles in simulator on Xcode 3.2.3, fails on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206999/static-library-dependency-compiles-in-simulator-on-xcode-3-2-3-fails-on-device). The halfway answer is that -all_load is causing the problem when targeting more than one architecture. The jury is still out on the definitive solution.